# File Managers - Colors by extension like Q-DIR for Windows

Tags: filemanager, colors

I have to use Windows at work and found Q-DIR, a great alternative to Windows Explorer, with a lot of missing features.

It has a very useful feature that I haven't found on any Linux (GUI) browser (I know you can do it on a terminal). With Q-DIR, you can assign a color to any file extension. For example, red to PDF, blue to .doc and .docx, green to .xls, etc.

It's a great feature when you have a lot of files in a folder (for example Downloads).

This is how it works:

[image: q-dir]

Does anyone know if there is a linux GUI file browser/manager that can handle this (by default or by using a plugin)? My file manager is Caja, but I also tried Nemo, Nautilus, PCManFM and others.

I know that you can do this with a terminal but I want to do this using a  GUI. I also know that you can assign colors to folders, but that's not what I want, I want to assign colors to extensions.

Answer (score 0):

"Double Commander" is a great file manager, and inter alia enables colours to be assigned to file types. Please let me know your chosen colour scheme.